# Shortest distance between nodes (say all homes) to a group of nodes (say hospitals) using NetworkX

Tags: networkx, shortest-path

Network nodes = residential units, hospitals

Network edges = roads with weight equal to the length

How can I calculate the shortest distance between each residential block to any hospitals nearby?

I used "nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length" and then filtered the shortest path to hospital nodes for each residential nodes. Is there a faster and better approach?

Comment: see A*, uses heuristics to 'bias' Dijkstra's towards the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your edges are all bidirectional.  If not, then see my modified algorithm at the bottom that reverses the graph.

Add a single node connected to all the hospitals with edge weight `1`.  Find the shortest path from all nodes to the added node.  The next-to-last node in any of these paths is a hospital, and the shortest path from a residential block to a hospital is the path to this added node truncated at the last node.

```
G.add_node('auxiliary_node')
for hospital in hospitals:
    G.add_edge(hospital, 'auxiliary_node', weight=1)

paths = nx.single_source_dijkstra_path(G,'auxiliary_node', weight='weight')
for path in paths:
    if path[-1] is a residential node:
        path.pop(0) #remove the first node, 'auxiliary_node'
        #the remaining path is the shortest path from a hospital to
        #path[-1].

        #code here to reverse the path so it's a path from the
        #residential block to its nearest hospital.  And 
        #to process the path however you want.

    else:
        #it is a hospital.  Ignore it.
```

If the weights are not symmetric, then reverse the graph.

```
H = G.reverse(copy=False)  #without copy=False it would make a new copy of
                           #the graph.  No need for that.
#same commands with H.
```